# How can I stop using Data Loader to assign owners to Campaign Members?

Tags: data-loader, campaign-member, salesforce-classic, custom-reports, excel

**Salesforce Enterprise Classic**

I have an outbound team of 10 individuals. We are calling contacts and leads for various reasons.

Our Marketing Automation Platform populates Salesforce Campaigns with Campaign Members.

Every week, it's my job to:

- Determine who we're calling next week
- Manually access each campaign and download the campaign members (using an SFDC report and exporting to CSV)
- Double check PTO / time off for the team to determine how many hours they're available
- In Excel, assign a "Call Owner" by entering their firstname.lastname on each line (so 200 calls = 200 lines, of course I use autocomplete or copy + paste).
- Repeat the previous 2 steps until the week's calls are ready
- Upload them using Data Loader

I feel like we can't be the only ones with this struggle. We don't use a power / progressive dialer (we're not telemarketing, it's more sales-focused).

There has to be a better way to do this, but I've beat my head against the wall and can't come up with an easier way to do it -- I also can't find anything on AppExchange that might solve my problem.

**Does anyone have any tips, tricks, or apps that can help this process become more automated?**

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to build this with a [Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build.htm&type=5) without too much difficulty. You can also write this in [Visualforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals), Lightning ([Aura](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) / [LWC](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics)). No matter how you look at it, some custom work is going to be required, but the complexity is entirely up to you. If you don't have an in-house developer/resource, Flows are a great way to write simple interfaces like this, although it may take some time to build. Custom code should generally be the "last resort" option, but what you're trying to do is definitely possible.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly -- it would work in a way that I would basically know how many calls each person gets per campaign (based on their available hours), and the flow can do the actual assignment work for me? I'm not well-versed in it, but I'm trying to visualize the functionality (and could be way off base, it could be too broad to even discuss here)

Comment: @James Yes, that's the gist of it. With Flows, the design choices are limited, but it is powerful enough to handle manipulating hundreds of records easily, which makes me think it might work out for you. Failing that, you can definitely do it in code, but that's going to require some expertise or costs of paying someone to do it for you. Basic crash course: describe the function you want, draw a mockup of it on paper how you visualize it, then research and develop. The better the planning phases, the better your results.